# Trying to get the propery of object but it is returning unexpected error in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have create a laravel object as per the documentation. Though when i am trying to get the value from it, it is throwing the error.

Here is a sample code

$user = USER::findOrFail(2990);

print_r($user);

This is throwing error. Please help me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Divert your attention to USER method. Part “orFail” hints at error if nothing found.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite hard to answer this without an exact error messsage.

This **could** be a case sensitivity issue. In Laravel, class names **should** be written in title case, but it seems you are using uppercase for "USER" instead of "User."

```php
$user = User::findOrFail(2990);
print_r($user);
```

It is also possible that it's just that **no user with ID 2990 exists**. And that throws an error. could you recheck if such a user exists?

Please upvode and accept if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all check in your database ( User Table ) what is the value of id = 2990

to print your variable try to use dd($user)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).